# How to access a Frame inside TabItem and delete it

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with some TabItems. One of them is dynamically filled with frames. 
[image]

```
var
  item: TListBoxItem;
  currentFrame: TFrame;
  frameIndex: integer;
begin
  if Sender is TListBoxItem then
    item:= TListBoxItem(Sender)
  else
    Exit;
  FindAndDeleteItemContext;
  frameIndex:= GetFrameIndexByText(item);
  {factory}
  FFramesFactory:= TFramesFactory.DefaultFactory;
  {new frame}
  currentFrame:= FFramesFactory.GetFrame(frameIndex);
  {add to layout}
  currentFrame.Parent:= TabItemContent;
  currentFrame.Align:= TAlignLayout.Client;
  //  TabItemContent.AddObject(currentFrame);
  TabItemContent.InsertComponent(currentFrame);
  {open tab}
  ActionToContentTabExecute(Sender); 
end;
```

In the FFramesFactory the frames are generated in the following way:

```
TFrame_Map.Create(nil)
```

Befor I add a new frame I want to find and delete the old frame without releasing it in the memory.

```
procedure Txxx.FindAndDeleteItemContext;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to Pred(TabItemContent.ComponentCount) do
  begin
    if TabItemContent.Components[i] is TFrame then
    begin
      TabItemContent.RemoveComponent(TabItemContent.Components[i]);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

but it isn't work. I can find the frame but  I can't delete it and I can see both frames in the tabitem.

How could I remove found frame?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove a component with `TabItemContent.RemoveComponent()`, you remove it from the `Components` list, iow **from the list of owned components**. **It is not removed from the children list** and therefore it remains visible on `TabItemContent`.

Since you want to keep it around in memory and only remove it visually from `TabItemContent`, you need to set its parent to `nil`:

```
  for i:= 0 to Pred(TabItemContent.ComponentCount) do
  begin
    if TabItemContent.Components[i] is TFrame4 then
    begin
      TControl(TabItemContent.Components[i]).Parent := nil; // remove visually
      // TabItemContent.RemoveComponent(TabItemContent.Components[i]); // remove from ownership
      // TabItemContent.Components[i].DisposeOf;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
```

If you want to release it after all, you should call `DisposeOf`.

Comment: What unit must I put in the uses so that the compiler knows `TTabItemContent` ?

Comment: @GuidoG There is nothing called `TTabItemContent` neither in the question nor the answer. There are two `TTabItem` instances, one called `TabItemContent` the other one called `TabItemDetails`. The `TTabControl` component discussed in this Q/A is declared in unit `FMX.TabControl`

Comment: I asked this because I am trying to do something similar in Rio, but the frame is not found on the tabitem, but on the tabitem there seems to be a control of type TTabItemContent and that holds my frame. I found that by looping thru TabItems.Controls[1].Controls. So, after `MyFrame.Parent = TabItem1` I cannot find the frame on TabItem1.Controls, but I can find it on `TabItem1.Controls[1].Controls` . And this `TabItem1.Controls[1]` is of type `TTabItemContent` (find by doing .ClassName on TabItem1.Controls[1] ).

Comment: Maybe I am missing `TabItem1.InsertComponent(MyFrame);`  ? Is this also needed after setting the parent of MyFrame ?

Comment: @GuidoG We can not start new discussions in comments. I suggest you post a proper question and provide your code as a [mre]. You can refer to this Q/A if it provides useful additional information.